# Python subplots placement

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

This must be a noob question but, how can I have two subplots that have (3/4) and (1/4) of the figure? Or 4/5 and 1/5

I tried with gridspec and simple subplots but I couldn't find a way. At the same time I am sure it is possible to do.

This is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_ticklabels_invisible(fig):
    for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
        ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax%d" % (i+1), va="center", ha="center")
        for tl in ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels():
            tl.set_visible(False)


plt.figure(0)
# ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0,0), colspan=3, rowspan=4)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0,1), colspan=1, rowspan=4)

plt.suptitle("subplot2grid")
make_ticklabels_invisible(plt.gcf())
plt.show()
```

ax1 and ax2 are fine if not placed together.

Comment: @PatrickArtner you are right, this is my code so far, I just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems I did not understand correctly how *loc* works. I managed to do it by changing those two lines:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0,0), colspan=3, rowspan=4)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0,3), colspan=1, rowspan=4)
```

instead of my previous:

```
# ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0,0), colspan=3, rowspan=4)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0,1), colspan=1, rowspan=4)
```

This is for 3/4 and 1/4 ratio.

I will not delete this question and later add an explanation of how loc works since it bugged me for some time, so that it exists as an archive.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the more natural way of defining the subplots all at once

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, gridspec_kw=dict(width_ratios=[3,1]))
```

[image]

This is a shortcut to the the following code using gridspec

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

gs = GridSpec(1,2, width_ratios=[3,1])

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
```